# Login: after going to another activity app forgot Facebook picture, and name text

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

i have two issues i can't figure out using Facebook SDK inside my Android app.

1. (SOLVED) After going to another activity, or re-open the app. It doesn't remember the profile picture, and the name(First, and Last name).
2. If you choose to log out it still display your name, and picture.

I would be very glad if someone could assist me with this.  Please provide code - not say just do that.   Thank you!

```
public class Profile extends Activity {
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */

WebView web;
ArrayList<NavigationDrawerItem> listItems;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
ListView list;

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private TextView name;


       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");
        final ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
        final TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("details", MODE_PRIVATE);
        //After referencing your Views, add this.
        String nameStr = sharedPrefs.getString("name", null);
        String idStr = sharedPrefs.getString("id", null);
        if(nameStr != null)
        {
            name.setText(nameStr);
        }
        if(idStr != null)
        {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(idStr);
        }
        //.. Do the same for other profile data


        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                com.facebook.Profile profile = com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                profilePictureView.getProfileId();
                profilePictureView.setProfileId(profile.getId());
                name.setText(profile.getName());

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString("name", profile.getName());
                editor.putString("id", profile.getId());
                //.. Do the same for other profile data
                editor.commit();

            }



            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
                Log.i("Error", "Error");
            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Login callback is called only if the login button is clicked. Try using `SharedPreferences` to store the name and other profile details.

Comment: @siris_cac  : Maybe you can provide a Answer, and some more info please :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the details in `SharedPreferences` and retrieve them.

Add this to your `onCreate()`.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("details", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In the `onSuccess()` of your callback add,

```
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", profile.getName());
editor.putString("id", profile.getId());
//.. Do the same for other profile data
editor.commit();
```

And in your `onCreate()` again,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("details", MODE_PRIVATE);
//After referencing your Views, add this.
String nameStr = sharedPrefs.getString("name", null);
String idStr = sharedPrefs.getString("id", null);
AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(token != null)
{
    if(nameStr != null)
    {
       name.setText(nameStr);
    }
    if(idStr != null)
    {
       profilePictureView.setProfileId(id);
    }
]
//.. Do the same for other profile data
```

Comment: I have issue with this line:   if(id != null)  - cannont resolve symbol id. Have updated my question with the code your posted.

Comment: Sorry. It should be idStr. Check the updated answer.

Comment: This  profilePictureView.setProfileId(id); should be                 profilePictureView.setProfileId(idStr); . (I have edited my answer. )  Problem 1 is now solved. Still issue with number 2.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please do some research before asking. These questions are pretty common. :)

Comment: Sorry for asking - but I am really stuck. There seem to be a issue finding symbol session, and method isOpened can not be resolved.  I have imported: import com.facebook.Session;

Comment: Thanks so much :) Still issue with number one.